# Find the files with same md5sum and print ones alike in the same line

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, md5sum

I'm trying to do one written in the title, I explain with one example:

Tree directory:
(A B C D H F G are my file)

```
dir0/
dir0/A    //MD5sum equal MD5sum B
dir0/C
dir0/D   // MD5sum equal MD5sum F G
dir0/dir1/B  // MD5sum equal MD5sum A
dir0/dir1/H
dir0/dir1/dir2/G  //MD5sum equal MD5sum F D
dir0/dir1/dir2/F  //MD5sum equal MD5sum G D
```

with this command:

```
find dir0/ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 md5sum | sort | uniq -w32 --all-repeated=prepend | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

I search all file in a dir0 and subdir, calculating the MD5sum, sort , select only files equals and divided into groups, print only path files.

Ok this works and I have this output:

```
dir0/A        ]
dir0/dir1/B   ] first group

dir0/D             ]
dir0/dir1/dir2/F   ]
dir0/dir1/dir2/G   ] second group
```

how can I have an output in the following way?(each file with the same MD5sum in the same line, obviously without " first, second ... group")

```
dir0/A dir0/dir1/B  ] first group
dir0/D dir0/dir1/dir2/F dir0/dir1/dir2/G ] second group
```

Comment: Without any sample input it's hard to say for sure, but are you just looking to get `awk` to output without a linefeed? Try `awk '{ printf "%s" $2 }'` instead of `awk '{ print $2 }'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortest way to do this would be to add a pipeline step like this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=RS RS}{$1=$1}1'
```

`RS = RS RS` causes Awk to use `"\n\n"` as its record separator, thus reading each block as a single record. The `FS` field separator is whitespace, which includes newlines, so we don't have to do any work to split the lines.

`$1 = $1` doesn't really change the value of `$1`, but Awk thinks it could have, which means it'll reconstruct `$0` (which currently has newlines in it) from `$1`, `$2`, etc., joining with `OFS` (which is `" "` by default).

`1` causes Awk to print `$0` (and `ORS`, which is still a single newline) on every record.